# Convert MySQL to postgres and retain default value

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have a MySQL database that I wish to convert into Postgres. One issue I encountered is to convert tinyint(1) (synonym to boolean) columns into "true" boolean and retain the default value of the MySQL column which can be either 0 or 1 but in Postgres the respective values are true or false. The SQL I'm trying:

```
ALTER TABLE "payments" ALTER COLUMN "is_automatic" TYPE boolean USING CAST("is_automatic" as boolean);
```

The error message:

```
ERROR:  default for column "is_automatic" cannot be cast automatically to type boolean
```

I would think it would be possible to cast this value somehow. Is this possible to do or do I have to manually add this to the migration script?

Edit: I realise I might have explained the issue a bit vaguely, sorry about that. I am using this script (https://github.com/lanyrd/mysql-postgresql-converter) to convert the MySQL database. The values are converted into "true" postgres boolean using this script just fine but the columns themselves that where originally booleans in MySQL (represented by tinyint(1)) gets their default value dropped. This happens on row 157 in the script and removing the "DROP DEFAULT" part of the command generates the error above, because it can't be casted (I guess). My question is better asked this way: In the process of converting a tinyint(1) column, can the default value be "remembered" and later applied again with a "SET DEFAULT" command?

Comment: I recommend you remove the ruby-on-rails tag here. There is nothing rails specific about your question.

Comment: Removed it. Thought it was going to be included, but it's not relevant indeed.

Answer (score 3):

The [postgresql ALTER TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altertable.html) reference page has an example exactly covering this scenario:

> .. when the column has a default expression that won't automatically
>   cast to the new data type:
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE foo
>     ALTER COLUMN foo_timestamp DROP DEFAULT,
>     ALTER COLUMN foo_timestamp TYPE timestamp with time zone
>     USING
>         timestamp with time zone 'epoch' + foo_timestamp * interval '1 second',
>     ALTER COLUMN foo_timestamp SET DEFAULT now();
> ```

So, you need to drop the old default, alter the type, then add the new default.

Note that the USING expression does not have any bearing on the default. It is purely used to convert existing values in the table. But in any case, there is no direct cast between integer and boolean, so you need a slightly more advanced USING expression.

Your statement might look like this:

```
ALTER TABLE payments 
    ALTER COLUMN is_automatic DROP DEFAULT, 
    ALTER COLUMN is_automatic TYPE BOOLEAN 
        USING is_automatic!=0, 
    ALTER COLUMN is_automatic SET DEFAULT TRUE;
```

The using expression might need a little tweaking, I am assuming here that your existing data has a value of 0 for false and something else for true.

Comment: I updated my question. The issue is purely the structure of the column and the default value of it. Sorry for any confusion. Basically I want the last row in your example statement "SET DEFAULT" to set it to either true or false based on what the integer column had. I realise this could be more of a feature request in the script (link above), because it might not be possible in one go with pure SQL(?)